D365: Show/Hide ribbon button based on statecode
I want to show Export to Excel and Export to PDF buttons when quote is in Active state and hide them when quote is in edit mode. I tried to do it from Ribbon Workbench as shown below, but buttons are not hidden as expected:

I know that this can be done also with javascript, but I would prefer to do it with a more simply way, with display/enable rules
